# Why does joining with an OR statement take so much longer than 2 queries on "AND"?

Tags: performance, join, time, left-join, proc-sql

I am wondering why in SAS if I perform either
 - 1 Join with an "OR" statement, or
 - 2 joins with "AND" and capturing both cases

decreases speed so much? I'm looking to learn more about the theory behind coding, joins, performance, etc.

I tried to look online but could not activate the key words necessary to find exactly what I'm looking for. I have prepared a case example

```
/*Take the baseball dataset and add a random number to each set*/
%MACRO test_or_join;
    %DO i = 1 %TO 200;
        DATA baseball_&i.;
            SET sashelp.baseball;
            rand = ranuni(&i.) * 493;
            iteration_1 = &i.;
            iteration_2 = &i.;
        RUN;
    %END;
    DATA baseball_merge_1;
        SET %DO i = 1 %TO 100;
                baseball_&i.
            %END;
        ;
    RUN;
    DATA baseball_merge_2;
        SET %DO i = 101 %TO 200;
                baseball_&i.
            %END;
        ;
        IF MOD(_N_,13) = 0 THEN ITERATION_1 = .;
    RUN;

    PROC DATASETS
        LIB=WORK;
        DELETE
            baseball_1 - baseball_2000;
    RUN;
%MEND;

%test_or_join;

PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE join_with_or   AS
    SELECT
          a.*
        , b.*
    FROM
        baseball_merge_1        A
    LEFT JOIN
        baseball_merge_2        B   ON  b.team = a.team                 AND
                                        (b.iteration_1 = a.iteration_1  OR
                                        b.iteration_2 = a.iteration_2);
QUIT;

PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE join_with_1    AS
    SELECT
          a.*
        , b.*
    FROM
        baseball_merge_1        A
    LEFT JOIN
        baseball_merge_2        B   ON  b.team = a.team                 AND
                                        b.iteration_1 = a.iteration_1;
QUIT;

PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE join_with_2    AS
    SELECT
          a.*
        , b.*
    FROM
        baseball_merge_1        A
    LEFT JOIN
        baseball_merge_2        B   ON  b.team = a.team                 AND
                                        b.iteration_2 = a.iteration_2;
QUIT;
```

The first join using "OR" takes 44.16 seconds
The two joins using just "AND" takes 0.47 & 0.44 seconds respectively

Comment: Your two queries are not the same. Add () to the one with the OR. If you fix that is the difference as dramatic?

Comment: I will try this

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. PS Were the missing parentheses the problem?